# Cannot WriteXML for DataTable because Windows Search Returns String Array for Authors Property

Tags: ado.net, ixmlserializable, windows-search, writexml

The `System.Author` Windows property is a multiple value string. *Windows Search* returns this value as an array of strings in a DataColumn. (The column's data-type is `string[]` or `String()`.) When I call the `WriteXML` method on the resulting data-table, I get the following `InvalidOperationException` exception.

Is there a way to specify the data-table's xml-serializer to use for specific columns or specific data-types?

Basically, how can I make `WriteXML` work with this data-table?

> System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   Type System.String[] does not
>   implement IXmlSerializable interface
>   therefore can not proceed with
>   serialization.

Comment: please show how you create the datatable...

Answer (score 1):

You could easily copy your DataTable changing the offending Authors column to a String and joing the string[] data with a proper delimiter like "|" or "; ".

```
DataTable xmlFriendlyTable = oldTable.Clone();
xmlFriendlyTable.Columns["Author"].DataType = typeof(String);
xmlFriendlyTable.Columns["Author"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
foreach(var row in oldTable.Rows) {
    object[] rowData = row.ItemArray;
    object[] cpyRowData = new object[rowData.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i<rowData.Length; i++) {
        if(rowData[i] != null && rowData[i].GetType() == typeof(String[])) {
            cpyRowData[i] = String.Join("; ", (rowData[i] as String[]));
        } else {
            cpyRowData[i] = rowData[i];
        }
        xmlFriendlyTable.Rows.Add(cpyRowData);
    }
}
xmlFriendlyTable.WriteXml( ... );
```

*NOTE* Wrote the above in the web browser, so there may be syntax errors.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the array to a `List<string>` rather than using a delimiter, even.